# Read at least x bytes until end of disc block in java

Tags: java, io

I want to read at least `x` bytes from a position in file, needed for immediately processing, and to cache the rest of disc block that the os read anyway, in case I'd need it in future.

I know I can read up to some block size (using `RandomAccessFile.read(byte[] b)`), but that way I may end up reading from another disc block even if all `x` bytes are in one block.

How can this be achived?

Comment: You can't. You have no control over how Java or OS caches and/or reads ahead from disk. If you *think* you know the disk block size, and you know the current position, you can calculate number of byte remaining in current block and only ask for that much.

Comment: @Andreas I see, thanks.